# ld: library not found for -lGGLCloudMessaging

Tags: ios, xcode, google-cloud-messaging

Getting "ld: library not found for -lGGLCloudMessaging" 
when compiling my project after adding GCM Pod
https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/client
My xcode build log:

```
Ld /Users/noamsegev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CodiPark-didqiygnaengxedykkrpmgdegpax/Build/Intermediates/CodiPark.build/Debug-iphoneos/Codipark.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CodiPark normal armv7
    cd /Users/noamsegev/git/codipark_ios_datapark/DATAPARK
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.1
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.0.sdk -L/Users/noamsegev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CodiPark-didqiygnaengxedykkrpmgdegpax/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -L/Users/noamsegev/git/codipark_ios_datapark/DATAPARK/ZBarSDK -L/Users/noamsegev/git/codipark_ios_datapark/DATAPARK/Codipark2 -L/Users/noamsegev/git/codipark_ios_datapark/DATAPARK/codipark2 -L/Users/noamsegev/git/codipark_ios_datapark/DATAPARK/ZBarSDK/Headers/ZBarSDK -L/Users/noamsegev/git/codipark_ios_datapark/DATAPARK/Codipark2/CardIO -F/Users/noamsegev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CodiPark-didqiygnaengxedykkrpmgdegpax/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/noamsegev/git/codipark_ios_datapark/DATAPARK -F/Users/noamsegev/git/codipark_ios_datapark/DATAPARK/Codipark2 -filelist /Users/noamsegev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CodiPark-didqiygnaengxedykkrpmgdegpax/Build/Intermediates/CodiPark.build/Debug-iphoneos/Codipark.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CodiPark.LinkFileList -miphoneos-version-min=7.1 -dead_strip -ObjC -lGGLCloudMessaging -lGGLCore -lGGLInstanceIDLib -lGSDK_Overload -lGTMSessionFetcher_core -lGTMSessionFetcher_full -lGTMStackTrace -lGTM_AddressBook -lGTM_DebugUtils -lGTM_GTMURLBuilder -lGTM_KVO -lGTM_NSData+zlib -lGTM_NSDictionary+URLArguments -lGTM_NSScannerJSON -lGTM_NSStringHTML -lGTM_NSStringXML -lGTM_Regex -lGTM_RoundedRectPath -lGTM_StringEncoding -lGTM_SystemVersion -lGTM_UIFont+LineHeight -lGTM_core -lGTM_iPhone -lGcmLib -lProtocolBuffers -lsqlite3 -lz -framework AddressBook -framework AssetsLibrary -framework CoreFoundation -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreLocation -framework CoreMotion -framework MessageUI -framework SystemConfiguration -force_load /Users/noamsegev/git/codipark_ios_datapark/DATAPARK/Pods/GoogleUtilities/Libraries/libGTM_NSData+zlib.a -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -stdlib=libc++ -framework ImageIO -framework CoreImage -framework MobileCoreServices -framework Security -framework EstimoteSDK -framework CoreBluetooth -framework CoreLocation -lCardIO -framework SystemConfiguration -lz -lsqlite3 -framework Instabug -lGoogleAnalyticsServices -framework CoreData -framework Foundation -framework GLKit -framework OpenGLES -framework MessageUI -framework CoreMotion -lzbar -lc++ -framework CoreTelephony -framework CoreGraphics -lGoogleAnalyticsServices -framework UIKit -framework AVFoundation -framework CoreMedia -framework CoreVideo -framework QuartzCore -liconv -framework AudioToolbox -lPods-Codipark -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/noamsegev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CodiPark-didqiygnaengxedykkrpmgdegpax/Build/Intermediates/CodiPark.build/Debug-iphoneos/Codipark.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CodiPark_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/noamsegev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CodiPark-didqiygnaengxedykkrpmgdegpax/Build/Intermediates/CodiPark.build/Debug-iphoneos/Codipark.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CodiPark
```

Comment: OK, edit your question to include the complete linker command line from the Xcode build log.

Comment: added Xcode  build log

Comment: @NoamSegev What does your pod file look like?

Comment: My Pod file # Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '6.0'

target 'Codipark' do
pod 'Google/CloudMessaging'
end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it by adding $(inherited) flag to Library Search Paths