# iOS GCM client implementation error:ld: library not found for -lGGLCloudMessaging

Tags: ios, google-cloud-messaging

I am facing the issue when implementing the gcm client in iOS. I set up everything and finally trying to run giving the following problem.

> Error: library not found for -lGGLCloudMessaging

[image]

Comment: is that library listed in the 'Linked Frameworks and Libraries' section ?

Comment: yes i added library in framework

Comment: Have you tried to implement the solution offered here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32972473/ld-library-not-found-for-lgglcloudmessaging

Comment: i added $(inherited) flag to Library Search Paths, still am getting same error